# Что должен возвращать catch?

Tags: c#, wpf, try-catch

Вот мой код:

```
// Чтение из файла
    private string ReadFile(string pathFile)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(pathFile))
            {
                string textFile = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return textFile;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Конечно имя метода `ReadFile()` подчёркнуто красным, так как не все строки кода возвращают значение. Что должен возвращать catch? Или я что-то пишу не так?

Comment: По-хорошему нужно просто кидать ошибку, а вызывающий ф-цию должен ее обработать.

Comment: вам не нужна эта функция, если вы можете использовать `File.ReadAllText(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return null;` или `return"";` а вообще, вы можете сделать общий `return` для функции.

```
private string ReadFile(string pathFile)
{
   string textFile = "";
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(pathFile))
        {
             textFile = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return textFile;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Проблема в том что метод должен вернуть какое-либо значение в любом случае

(только если не было брошено исключение)

Инструкцию возврата можно добавить в любом из двух мест:

```
// Чтение из файла
private string ReadFile(string pathFile)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(pathFile))
        {
            string textFile = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return textFile;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        // <-- можно добавить тут
    }
    // <-- или тут
}
```

Обычно в таком случае возвращают `null` или пустую строку `""`, в зависимости от того как и где вы потом это вызываете.

Проверить можно вот так:

```
var fileText = ReadFile("file.txt");

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileText)) {
   MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!");
}
```

Так же советую не использовать `StreamReader` для чтения файлов.

Есть уже готовые методы: `File.ReadAllText()`, `File.ReadAllBytes()`

Comment: Я бы сказал, что пустую строку при ошибке возвращать нельзя, так как это может восприниматься как факт того, что файл пуст. В то время как он просто может не существовать.

Comment: Что касается этих слов - "Так же советую не использовать StreamReader для чтения файлов.Есть уже готовые методы: File.ReadAllText(), File.ReadAllBytes())" 
пусть будет тут ссылка:)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545402/any-difference-between-file-readalltext-and-using-a-streamreader-to-read-file

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, в данном случае код должен пробрасывать исключение выше по коду.

Если я попытаюсь прочитать файл данным методом и получу строку, то буду полагать, что файл просто пустой, хотя на самом деле путь может быть невалидный и все такое.

Что бы показать, что ваш метод может вернуть значение или нет, в C# принято создавать методы с приставкой `Try*`.

```
private bool TryReadFile(string pathFile,out string result)
```

В итоге, благодаря возможностям C# 7.0+ можно писать такие конструкции:

```
if (TryReadFile(@"c:\blablabla.txt",out var result))
{
 Console.WriteLine(result)
}
```